# How to map native SQL query result to a list of custom value types in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, native-sql, iusertype

I have a value type called `FiscalYear` which essentially is a wrapper for an integer. I have also implemented the `NHibernate.UserTypes.IUserType` for it. Now I can map properties of type `FiscalYear` directly to SQL Types and NHibernate will convert them automatically.

It all works fine. But now I would like to perform a native SQL query to get a list of fiscal years from the database. Here is the current code:

```
public IEnumerable<FiscalYear> FiscalYears
{
    get
    {
        var result = new List<FiscalYear>();
        foreach (var fiscalYear in Session.CreateSQLQuery(FiscalYearsQuery).List<Int16>())
        {
            result.Add(new FiscalYear(fiscalYear));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Is works, but my question is: since I have already implemented the `IUserType` for `FiscalYear`, is it possible to simplify this code to something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<FiscalYear> FiscalYears
{
    get
    {
        return Session
            .CreateSQLQuery(FiscalYearsQuery)
            .List<FiscalYear>();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Using `Transformers.AliasToBean` doesn't help either, since `FiscalYear` is a value type and not an entity.

I think this is really something that should be easy to do, but all my attempts so far failed. I guess I'm just missing something out?

Comment: I don't think there is a support for this

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post:

[NHibernateUtil.Custom()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799457/nhibernate-hql-and-usertypes-as-query-paramaters)

There it is described, that you can use  NHibernateUtil.Custom(IUserType)

Answer (score -1):

When you use `CreateSQLQuery` you must add the types of the returning values, i have never used native sql queries with custom types, but you can try:

```
return Session
    .CreateSQLQuery(FiscalYearsQuery)
    .AddScalar("*QueryColumnName*", FiscalYear)
    .List<FiscalYear>();
```

If this not works you can implement `IResultTransformer` for more elegant way to convert your data.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't even valid syntax. Furthermore, apart from column name, `AddScalar` only accepts an instance of `NHibernate.Type.IType`, which `NHibernate.UserTypes.IUserType` does not extend, and hence `FiscalYearType` does not implement. Implementing `IResultTransformer` is an option, but it would only make it worse, since all I am trying to do is make the code simpler, not more complicated.

Comment: Sorry if i can't see how can be more complicated add one line of code calling your transformer instead a foreach.

Comment: True, using `IResultTransformer` is one line of code, but then I would have to implement it, and it would be more than one line of code, and probably more than a foreach. I just thought that it all would be unnecessary since i have already got the `IUserType` implemented...